# Angular JS populating checkbox in ng-repeat withJSON array based on the array object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I am populating the checkbox in a really bad way in a loop. I have tried various other ways I found online but can't get it to work.

Looking for the most performance efficient way to do this as I have 5000+ records with 12 check boxes each.

JSON:

```
{"clients":
[{"year":2015,"clientId":1,"clientName":"Durand  
months":[
{"name":"Jan","submitted":false,"submittedBy":"NA"},     
{"name":"Apr","submitted":true,"submittedBy":"NA"}
]}]}
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in clients |  orderBy: 'clientRef'">
<td id="clientName">{{ x.clientName }}</td>
<td>    
<div ng-repeat = "month in x.months">
<div ng-if="month.name =='Apr'">
<input ng-model="month.submitted" id="apr" type="checkbox"  />
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: have you tried with ng-checked? for example :  ng-checked="month.submitted"

Comment: http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Comment: @Phil my json doesn't come back in the order I have to display each month